# How to utilize the Windows Vista/7 Dialogs?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, dialog, pinvoke

I have noticed that the Windows Vista/7 dialogs look MUCH better than just a MessageBox. How can I use them with a P/Invoke?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`TaskDialogIndirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb760544%28VS.85%29.aspx) method.

You can also use the [Windows API Code Pack](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/WindowsAPICodePack/), which contains a managed wrapper.

Comment: "Minimum DLL Version comctl32.dll version 6"

Comment: @Pindatjuh: He asked that before I edited in the link.  Obviously, it requires Vista.